# New Out of the box Community using Winter 15 release Napili template: NewCase error

Tags: community, case

We've set up a new community using the Community designer from Winter release 14 and when we click on "Contact Support" from the main page or from the "Post To" option in the "Ask the Community" drop -down, we get an error saying:

> "Either this publisher action does not exists or you don't have access
>   to it: NewCase"

Here is a screencast of what we see:
http://screencast.com/t/lpcajr2Ov

I read through the list of know issues but could not find this one:
(https://success.salesforce.com/issues_index?page=3&tag=Communities)

I also submitted a **question to the Developer Forum** stating that all users & profiles I've configured for the community including the one I used to test, are set to access Cases and related objects. 
(see the post here: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000AnB3IAK)

On a Developer suggestion, I made sure the "NewCase" pub action was included in our proper Case page layouts as well as the Global Publisher Layout.

Lastly, I updated the Profiles and Permission sets according to the "Getting Started with Communities" guide (pg 25); 
(http://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_communities_implementation.pdf)

We are still getting this error and I really need help figuring out what's missing!

Please help!

Comment: per the Salesforce Community implementation page, this is a known issue when you are using an org with a namesepace prefix - see [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000AnB3IAK) for the specific details. Conversation on the community is [here](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?fId=0D53000001ftIH5&g=0F9300000001og8).

Answer (score 7):

I'm still new to this but something that worked for me is:

1. Go to Setup > Create > Global Actions
2. Create a new Global Action

   - Target object = case
   - Record type = I set this to the kind of case I wanted to be created in the Service console
   - Label = name it whatever you'd like. This is how it shows up in Global Actions
   - save

[image]

3. Go back to Site.com and open the Site Page you want to edit
   [image]
4. In the "Contact Support" element change the "Signed-in User Case Action" to the Global Action label that you created earlier
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I just had this very issue, and I found the Success Community post listed by Nick Martin on this article was exactly the fix (forget the Namespace issues). https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AnB3IAK
It is similar to the answer above as in you have to create a Global Action, but you have to then put the Global Action on the Global Publisher Layout, and there is some playing around with Record Types required. I got it all working quite successfully with a different create case layout for logged in users vs anonymous access (in this case they need to enter their Name, Email, Company etc). This was also in the new Community Builder, rather than in the site.com setup.